# Angular 5+ routerLinkActive doesn't work with repeated parameters

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

In my little example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7eqku) everything works fine with the following paths:

> https://angular-d7eqku.stackblitz.io/path1
>
> https://angular-d7eqku.stackblitz.io/path1?param1=1

but if I use repeated query parameters to pass an array of values routerLinkActive brakes:

> https://angular-d7eqku.stackblitz.io/path1?param1=1&param1=2

Is it a bug? How can I bypass it?
**Tested it in Angular 5/6.**

**Update:**
I updated my example a bit to show why I want to pass an array of parameters exactly this way (not passing it as one parameter with multiple values) and how I use it.

**Update2:**
After deletion of [queryParamsHandling]="'preserve'" it starts working, so the question can be narrowed to:
**Why routerLinkActive doesn't work with repeated parameters when queryParamsHandling="preserve".**

Answer (score 1):

To pass an array to query params you probably have to use `,` ,so the link should look like this:

`https://angular-d7eqku.stackblitz.io/path1?param1=1,2`

route snapshot (ActivatedRoute.snapshot) will look like this:

```
{
  ...
  queryParams: {
    param1: "1,2"
  },
  ...
}
```

*UPDATE:*

Alright, misunderstood the question. So if you change your app.component.html to the following code - it will work:

```
<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="path1" routerLinkActive="active">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="path2" routerLinkActive="active">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="path3" routerLinkActive="active">Item1</a></li>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ul>
```

[Here is repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zviy3y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)  navigate to `path1?param1=1&param1=3` and it will display the values and highlight the active url

Comment: I'd like to use a standard way since it is supported by angular (https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#getall) without mapping may array into/from a string.

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov ParamMap is only for url-parameters, ie when you declared your route as `home/:my-param/:id`;   here are docs about query params https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: There is queryParamMap of type ParamMap in ActivatedRoute. You can see how it works in my example.

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov what's the problem with using coma (`,`) in your query params and then simply make an array from that string?

Comment: If you try https://angular-d7eqku.stackblitz.io/path1?param1=1,2 on my example you will see that it's not working.

Comment: yeah, because you don't have to join those strings, here is working stakblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zviy3y?file=src/app/test-route.component.ts

Comment: okay, let's start from the beginning :) Your example works only because it is one parameter. My question is not about how I can make it one parameter but why it's not working with repeated parameters even though I see that in other parts of Angular repeated parameters are supported by design.

Comment: so basically you just deleted `[queryParamsHandling]="'preserve'"`?

Comment: Correct, seems like this directive is conflicting with `routerLinkActive`